# How to move background with keys in pygame

Tags: python, pygame, background, horizontal-scrolling, vertical-scrolling

I am trying to make a game with pygame where the player is fixed in the center of the map. When you press a key, the background moves instead of the player, but I've only managed to do that on the x-axis. When implementing it on the y-axis, the background goes crazy.

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
            
            if event.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit() 
                sys.exit()
            
        pulsar = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if pulsar[pygame.K_a] or pulsar[pygame.K_LEFT]:

            x += 2
        if pulsar[pygame.K_d] or pulsar[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
           
            x -= 2

        x_relativa = x % bg.get_rect().width
        screen.blit(bg, (x_relativa - bg.get_rect().width, y))

        if x_relativa < width:
            screen.blit(bg, (x_relativa, 0))
```

This code shows how I make the background scroll on the x-axis with the A and D keys. Changing these values ​​to the y-axis also works independently but not at the same time

Answer (score 0):

I don't exactly understand how your code works, but I do know that the following works:

```py
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type==QUIT:
        running=False
presseds=pygame.key.get_pressed()
if presseds[K_UP] or presseds[K_w]:
    bgrect.y+=5
if presseds[K_DOWN] or presseds[K_s]:
    bgrect.y-=5
if presseds[K_RIGHT] or presseds[K_d]:
    bgrect.x-=5
if presseds[K_LEFT] or presseds[K_a]:
    bgrect.x+=5
screen.fill((0,0,0))
screen.blit(bg,bgrect)
```

In this code, bgrect is the rect of your background's surface.